# Nodejs and npm installation on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, npm

I am pursuing a course which asked me to install Nodejs and npm using below commands. But I am not able to understand the very first command, what exactly it is doing and how to write it on the terminal.

$ sudo bash -c "cat >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list" <

deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x xenial main

deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x xenial main
EOL

$ curl -s https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -

$ sudo apt update

$ sudo apt install nodejs

I checked the Nodejs site and they are just recommending below command to install Nodejs

curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

Please guide me what should I do, I have to install Nodejs v6.9 and npm version 3.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to you to install required Node version via [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). NVM is tool that helps you to change Node version on your machine. So you can use any Node version you want, even 6.9.

In order to install NVM you have to run this command:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.9/install.sh | bash
```

You can verify NVM installation with this command:

```
command -v nvm
```

After that you can install required version of Node:

```
nvm install v6.9
```

If you install multiple version of Node, you can switch from one version to another:

```
nvm use v6.9
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan, Can you please compare the commands which I have mentioned in my question with the NVM you are providing, will it make any changes to the packages or will it make any difference to my current setup. Also will NVM install the npm version 3.x as well? Please pardon me, as I am new to linux.

Comment: Commands that you have used are installing Node version itself. You are basically adding to Ubuntu source manager, repository where he can find Node and after that telling him to install it. NVM is tool that is used for managing Node version on your local machine. So you can use on ubuntu whichever version you need. I am not sure for npm version I would need to check that. Also I would suggest you to uninstall node version that you have installed before installing NVM. `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove nodejs` -> should do the job

Answer (score 0):

You can install a specific version of NodeJS using NVM:

```
sudo apt-get install curl
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.9/install.sh | bash
```

Now close the terminal and open it again and type:

```
command -v nvm
```

If the terminal outputs `nvm` you're good to go.

Next you can install the version you want:

```
nvm install 6.9.0
nvm use 6.9.0
```

And if everything is ok, it should output you this:

```
Now using node v6.9.0 (npm v3.10.8)
```